# How to remove the space between paragraphs (p)

Tags: html, css

How can I remove spaces between paragraphs in HTML?

```
<p class="first">This is a small demo</p>
<p class="second">This is second demo</p>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `margin: 0;` to remove the spaces.

```
p { margin: 0; }
```

If this still don't work, try making it `!important`

```
p { margin: 0 !important; }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/zg7fP/1/

Comment: You can check the demo.

Comment: Can u try p { margin: 0 !important; }

Comment: Thanks, it did work for me. Is there any specific reason why it didn't without !important

Comment: Yes might be some other css file being used and they tend to override your styling. Updating the answer.

Comment: Detail about the !important tag : http://www.impressivewebs.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-important-css-declaration/

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `margin-bottom: 0` on the top paragraph and `margin-top: 0` to the bottom paragraph

or you can use a div instead of the paragraph

Comment: No its not working. And aslo i can't change the html code, its generating automatically.

Comment: Is there another CSS file/property that may be overriding your declaration? This does work pretty well in JSfiddle.

Comment: Yes some couple of css were there, but had never such idea about css overiding. Thanks for ur help

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default margin to zero with CSS:

```
p {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `line-height: 100%;` or other percentage you think it feets well on your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `p {margin: 0 auto;}`

In case you want to add indentation (recommended if you remove spaces between paragraphs) a good technique is:

```
p + p {text-indent: 1.25em;}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using bootstrap this is the solution: the class m-0

```
<p class="m-0">text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

put both inside a single set of
    p and seperate with br

Answer (score 0):

There are a range of "m-x" classes you can add to paragraph elements where x (0+) represent integers driving increasing space between paragraphs:

For example, this will have no space between the paragraphs:

```
<p class="m-0">hello world</p>
<p class="m-0">hello world</p>
```

For example, this will have a bit more:

```
<p class="m-1">hello world</p>
<p class="m-1">hello world</p>
```

For example, this will have yet more:

```
<p class="m-2">hello world</p>
<p class="m-2">hello world</p>
```

And so on...